# Polar graph question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, polar-coordinates

Can you only graph periodic functions using polar graphing? I'm not really understanding this I guess. It you are to get all of the x and y values on a finite graph, then the original must be periodic, no?

Comment: There is a mapping between polar coordinates and rectangular coordinates.

Comment: If you try to get y=2x into polar coordinates en you get r=0. How is this? So the polar form of y=2x would be a point?

Comment: The answer to your question is probably "no," but I'm not 100% sure I actually understand what you're asking.  Are you asking if a function $r = f(\theta)$ necessarily fits inside of a finite region of the plane (in which case the answer is no), or something else?

Comment: As to $y = 2x$, this is a line through the origin.  Any line through the origin can be written as $\theta = C$ for some constant $C$.

Comment: y=2x means $r\sin\theta=2r\cos\theta$. $r$ can be ANY value that you can think of in the reals. However, $\tan\theta=2$

Comment: $y=2x$ is in polar, $\theta = \arctan(2)$

Comment: Oh ok. So anything can be transformed into polar form?

Comment: I tried graphing theta=arctan2 and it says I can't graph that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily. Recall that:

$$r^2=x^2+y^2$$

$$x=r\cos \theta$$

$$y=r\sin \theta$$

You can manipulate that to graph non-periodic functions. Take for instance $y=2x^2$.

$$r^2=x^2+(2x^2)^2=x^2+4x^4$$
$$r=x\sqrt{1+4x^2}$$

Plug in for $x$ what we said earlier, $r\cos \theta$:

$$r=r\cos \theta\sqrt{1+4(r\cos \theta)^2}$$
$$1=\cos \theta \sqrt{1+4r^2\cos^2\theta}$$
$$\left(\frac1{\cos \theta}\right)^2-1=4r^2\cos^2 \theta$$
Too lazy to simplify:

$$r=\sqrt{\frac{\left(\frac1{\cos \theta}\right)^2-1}{4\cos^2 \theta}}$$

When you graph it, you'll get the graph of $y=2x^2$.